# Implementing Dictionary with multiple Search Keys and Value

Tags: c#, dictionary, data-structures, lookup

I have a list of 40,000 rows in a Schedule Table having value based on five key columns. The table Looks like this -

```
Date    Location    Schedule Id Type    Lane    Value
1/1/2019    Paris   Sched - 1   Rural   <null>  34.94
1/1/2019    Paris   Sched - 1   Rural   <null>  35.41
1/1/2019    Paris   Sched - 1   Rural    101    39.45
1/1/2019    Paris   Sched - 1   Urban    101    94.23
1/1/2019    Paris   Sched - 1   <null>   101    24.87
1/1/2019    Paris   Sched - 1   <null>  <null>  33.38
```

I have a requirement for processing million of records to find the values based on the keys in each record.  A record may contain any combination of the keys where first three keys are mandatory, but next two keys may or may not have values. The Schedule table have unique rows for the combination  of these five keys

I am looking for some suggestion on the right data structure to use to store the Schedule Table. I thought of using List, but as I understand, Lists are not as efficient as Dictionary, however dictionary can be defined only with one key.

Appreciate if someone can suggest a a better way to implement this solution.

```
--- Edit --
```

A small correction. By "but next two keys may or may not have values." I mean, they may have null values, still the combination of first 5 keys is going to remain unique.

Comment: A dictionary can have only a single key, but that doesn't mean that the key itself can't be a type containing however many different properties you need...

Comment: Use Dictionary<Tuple<DateTime, string, string, string, int?>, decimal>

Comment: Why not delegate this into a SQL database with proper indexes?

Comment: `"processing million of records"` -- Use SQL

Comment: You state that _The Schedule table have unique rows for the combination of these five keys_, yet the first two rows in your sample dataset have equal keys. So, are duplicates in your data, or not?

Comment: SQL. The answer is always SQL. This is literally exactly the kind of thing it exists for.

Comment: When you say the `next two keys may or may not have values`, what does that mean for lookup? If `Type` is `<null>` then what searches should match that row?

Comment: @maccettura, gerardo-grignoli, ian and all , Thanks for your suggestions. Using SQL is not a solution for reason that the Sourcedb is in remote location, Querying individual records against million of rows is what making this job run for 8 hours. I did a PoC to bring the data in memory and run the job which has reduced the time to less than a couple of hours, still I feel there is a possibility to make it run in under 30 mins if i can choose a better data structure and indexing method.

Comment: @NetMage last two keys may have null values. Still the Combination of first 5 key will remain unique considering null as a value.

Comment: @AtulJain Then why does your sample data not meet that criteria? Also, what type of data structure holds the "Schedule Table"?

Answer (score 0):

Use a `Dictionary<ScheduleTableKey, double>` (assuming values are of type `double`), where `ScheduleTableKey` is a structure consisting of all the key columns. You'll get a close-to O(1) complexity.

For example:

```
struct ScheduleTableKey {
    DateTime Date;
    string   Location;
    string   Schedule_Id;
    string   Type;
    int?     Lane;
}

var table = new Dictionary<ScheduleTableKey, double>();
```

Note that different types of the struct's members may be more appropriate, based on your case.

Comment: This exactly structure won't work because he has duplicates.  It probably should be a `Dictionary<Schedule, List<Double>>` and always mention that if you use a custom class, as the Key in a dictionary, the class should implement `IEquatable<T>` and override both `Equals` and `GetHashCode()`.

Comment: @ErikPhilips He specifically states, that the 5-column key is unique: _The Schedule table have unique rows for the combination of these five keys_

Comment: I think he's confusing the nominclature `unique`.  He should just say there is a `key` but as you can clearly see by the first two rows of the *The table Looks like this* are duplicates via that key.

Comment: @ErikPhilips Oh, didn't notice that. I asked OP for clarification.

Comment: Thanks MartinHeralecký, @ErikPhilips, I meant the combination of first 5 key is unique, where the last two keys may have nulls

Wondering what if we create a Key table with first three attributes (Date, Location, Schedule Id) and then create a list of items with last three key  attributes (Type, Land, Value). That way, when the record on key is found, a list or liner search can be implemented to find the appropriate combination. 

one problem is the to know how much time it will take to build such a dictionary before it can be used, and the time to fetch individual record.

Answer (score 0):

A `Dictionary` will take up storage for all the keys and Values, but will only take a hundredths of a second to create from 40,000 records and will let you lookup values very efficiently.

Assuming `src` is an `IEnumerable<>` that contains your Schedule Table, you can convert to a dictionary with

```
var ValueMap = src.ToDictionary(s => new { s.Date, s.Location, s.ScheduleId, s.Type, s.Lane }, s => s.Value);
```

Then you can lookup values with:

```
var k = new { Date, Location, ScheduleId, Type, Lane };
var value = ValueMap[k];
```

If you don't know if a particular key will exist in the Schedule Table, you can use

```
if (ValueMap.TryGetValue(k, out var value)) {
    // use value here
}
else {
    // there is no matching value
}
```

If available (e.g. C# 7) using a `ValueTuple` will be faster to process and generate no garbage when doing millions of lookups if that matters.

```
var ValueMap = src.ToDictionary(s => (s.Date, s.Location, s.ScheduleId, s.Type, s.Lane), s => s.Value);

var k = (Date, Location, ScheduleId, Type, Lane);
var value = ValueMap[k];
```